# windows Server 2016 - Boot into command prompt not safe mode

Tags: windows-server-2016

Is it possible to boot Windows server 2016 into a command prompt in such a way, that it leaves the disks and file systems where they are? I'm not looking for safe mode. When I hit F8 on boot up, I can get into the "safe mode" menu, (that of course has other options). However, my C:\ does not have the same folder structure, and I have a new "X:\" disk. I would like to get into a command prompt where the disks are left alone, and I don't have this new X:\ drive, with "some" of what was on C:. My C:\ only has the two Program file's folder and that's it. Is this possible?

Comment: Safe Mode is for diagnostics and repair, so the drive letters really shouldn't matter (as you're not intended to be running your usual stuff in the usual way, while in Safe Mode).  Why do you need to open a command prompt instead of Explorer?  What is your actual goal?  If you don't want a GUI, why not use a Core or a Nano server install instead of a full "Desktop Experience" install?

Comment: I understand what safe mode is intended to do. I don't know why it creates a separate drive (X:\) and why it changes the C:\ filesystem. I'm curious as to why this occurs, and if their is an option to change Safe mode, to not create a X:\ and not modify my C:\ . Yes, I could use a Nano/Core. but that doesn't give me an answer as to why this occurs.

Comment: "Is this possible?" is not the same as "why does this happen?"  this is a Q&A site about actual computer problems. "WHY" MS does anything can usually only be answered by MS (aside from opinion-based assumptions and guesses).  What's the actual problem you're having, what have you tried already to resolve it, and what's your specific (non-"WHY") question you need us to answer so you can achieve your goal?

Comment: Ok, is it possible to change this behavior? IS it possible to get safe mode to not create an X:\ and not change the C:\ file  system? (I don't think its changing it, but running a DIR doesn't show what it shows normally)

Comment: No; but safe mode doesn't do that, x: is used by WinRE not safe mode.  You have changed the drive while in whatever mode your right? to the correct partition.